# Autenticación e inicio de sesión de tipos de usuarios PHP

Tags: php, mysql, autenticación

Estoy trabajando en un inicio de sesión, pero necesito validar a diferentes tipos de usuarios. En este caso son:

- 1 = Usuario final
- 2 = Admin
- 3 = Superusuario

En la siguiente manera puedo acceder a solo uno de ellos pero necesito que al logearse automáticamente sepa que tipo de usuario es.

Éste es el código que estoy manejando, pero aun soy nueva y no lo entiendo del todo.

El siguiente código es el que estoy utilizando:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>

      <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="res/bootstrap3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Add custom CSS here -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<?php

// define('LBROOT',getcwd()); // LegoBox Root ... the server root
// include("core/controller/Database.php");

if(!isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) {
$user = $_POST['email'];
$pass = sha1(md5($_POST['password']));

$base = new Database();
$con = $base->connect();
$sql = "select * from user where (email= \"".$user."\" or username= \"".$user."\") and password= \"".$pass."\" and is_active='1'";
//print $sql;
$query = $con->query($sql);
$found = false;
$userid = null;
while($r = $query->fetch_array()){
    $found = true ;
    $userid = $r['id'];
}

if($found==true) {
//  session_start();
//  print $userid;
    $_SESSION['user_id']=$userid ;
//  setcookie('userid',$userid);
//  print $_SESSION['userid'];

    print "Espere porfavor ... $user";




    print "<script>window.location='index.php?view=home';</script>"; 

}else {
    print "<script>window.location='index.php?view=login';</script>";
}

}else{
    print "<script>window.location='index.php?view=home';</script>";
}
?>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por parte de la comunidad. ¿Podrías facilitarnos **la estructura de la tabla de usuarios** y/o aquella que uses para guardar los niveles de acceso? Por cierto, tu código puede sufrir los [graves problemas de seguridad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY) asociados a la [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyección_SQL).

Answer (score 2):

Lo primero que necesitas es alterar el esquema de la tabla para agregar un campo con el nivel de acceso del usuario:

```
ALTER TABLE user
  ADD nivel TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
```

Con esta instrucción SQL agregamos un campo de tipo `TINYINT` (de -128 a 127) que no permite valores vacíos y que, por defecto (si no se indica), dará privilegios de usuario normal a los nuevos registros.

Además, he puesto comentarios en tu código con diferentes cambios:

```
<?php
/* El código lo ponemos al comienzo, no entre el HTML. En caso contrario
  "session_start()" no podrá mandar las cabeceras necesarias para establecer la cookie */
session_start();
/* Además, esta comprobación no funcionaría porque $_SESSION no estaría disponible */
if (empty($_SESSION['user_id']) === true) {
  $base = new Database();
  $con = $base->connect();
  /* Escapamos la cadena para poder agregarla al SQL con seguridad */
  $user = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
  /* Un picadillo sha1 no necesita ser escapada, pero (*) */
  $pass = sha1(md5($_POST['password']));
  $sql = "
    SELECT * FROM user
    WHERE (email = '$user' OR username = '$user')
      AND password = '$pass'
      AND is_active = '1'
  ";
  $query = $con->query($sql);
  $r = $query->fetch_array();
  /* No necesitas una variable auxiliar "$found" */
  if ($r !== false) {
    /* Guardamos el "id" de usuario y el "nivel" de acceso */
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $r['id'];
    $_SESSION['nivel'] = $r['nivel'];
    /* Redirigimos a la URL interna */
    header('Location: index.php?view=home');
    /* Finalizamos esta script */
    die();
  }
}
/* Redirigimos a la URL de inicio de sesión indicando fallo */
header('Location: index.php?view=login&fallo=1');
```

PD: He de advertirte que el código sufre de los [graves problemas de seguridad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY) asociados a la [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL) que debe solucionarse con consultas preparadas o usando [`mysqli::real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysqli.real-escape-string) como te he propuesto en el código.